# The name of this "incredulous" face expression?

Tags: phrase-requests

A very similar expression to the one I mean can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/LcmBALxDkRY?t=1m38s) (the girl at 1:38).

[image]

Mouth slightly open (upper teeth showing), eyes almost or at least slightly closed, head also slightly tilted to one side, and a small head shake.

What's the name for this expression, or a way to quickly describe it?

E.g.

> "What?" she asked as she shook her head in disbelief.

(Don't think that's accurate though.)

Comment: I think you already nailed it: an *incredulous* look, or *shaking her head in disbelief*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word choice depends on the degree of surprise/bafflement provoked by someone's behaviour.

A ***quizzical*** reaction to someone's behaviour (i.e. *mild puzzlement* (OED), allowing the possibility that there may be a reasonable explanation), or an ***incredulous*** reaction (i.e. *frank disbelief* (OED) that someone should actually do such a thing).

Answer (score 2):

I like the expression **quizzical**

> [**quizzical**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quizzical) (OD)
>
> (Of a person’s expression or behaviour) indicating mild or amused puzzlement:
>   *she gave me a quizzical look*

Rowan Atkinson from the BBC TV comedy series, *Blacck Adder*, perfected the art of the quizzical expression.

[image]

Comment: No, she's disbelieving. Or can quizzical be used for disbelieving / incredulous?

Comment: Doesn't she look confused in the image, as if she were saying *What are you getting at?* Mildly puzzled, as if questioning the person's claim/behaviour/opinion. I suppose *disbelief* fits better. But I like the word *quizzical*, and I don't care about the upvotes or downvotes. Not on this type of answers.

Comment: In the video, she's not so much confused as calling bullshit, saying "no way!". But you're right, questioning (quizzing!) the guy's behavior is one way to put it. There is no doubt in her mind that he's wrong/weird, but she might be questioning why he's doing it at all.

Comment: @DanBron the next time a neologism contest comes around, I hope you submit *wrongweird* defined as Steve Buscemi.

Answer (score 2):

To me, her face is saying, "I can't believe you did/would do that." Specifically, it says this with a condescending/snide/sardonic expression - as if mocking someone she knows (or maybe doesn't know) for a bone-headed action.

Answer (score 0):

Exasperation?  That is when, for instance, you explain carefully, twice, how to do something, and the person does it wrongly, twice, and also breaks something on the second try.